# Close Powerpoint Window using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, activex, powerpoint

I am currently using an activeX-server object (named PP in the code) to write a powerpoint presentation (pres) from MATLAB. At the end, I close the presentation. This causes powerpoint to close the presentation, what a surprise, but leaves a powerpoint window open. If I close the PP object, all powerpoints currently open, not only those I wrote, are closed. The problem is that all powerpoint windows share one process and PP.Quit() kills that process. Is there any way to close one specific powerpoint window without killing the powerpoint process?

```
PP = actxserver('PowerPoint.Application');
do stuff
pres = PP.Presentations.Open(fileName);
pres.Close(); %<- Closes the presentation, but an empty powerpoint window is still open.
PP.Quit(); % <- That is the problem
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
PP.Quit;
PP.delete;
```

instead of:

```
pres.Close(); %<- Closes the presentation, but an empty powerpoint window is still open.
PP.Quit(); % <- That is the problem
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem is, that I'll still close all opened powerpoint windows as PP.Quit kills the Powerpoint Singleton. Your answer won't work for me.

Comment: Strange. I use it in a similar way with Microsoft Excel and it does not close all the other windows. I also see that you assign your opening function to a variable

Comment: PP = actxserver('PowerPoint.Application');
do stuff
PP.Presentations.Open(fileName);
PP.Quit;
PP.delete;

Comment: Excel works differently as it isn't a singleton. We see this behavior only with Powerpoint...

Comment: After calling .Close on your presentation, query PP.Presentations.Count. If it's zero, call PP.Quit.  If it's > 0, then there are other presentations open, so don't call .Quit on the app.

Comment: Thanks Steve! I would still have the one open window, but only if there is  another Powerpoint opened. Should be a reasonable workaround.